# Error restarting cluster: waiting for apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

when i run `sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none` . I'm getting this error :

```
Error restarting cluster: waiting for apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition

  Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself found an answer so I'm posting it here .
Try `minikube delete` and rerun this command